# computed property not working on controller accessed though the needs-property

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Somehow the computed property of a controller I'm accessing through the needs property won't work in the template. Other regular string properties work as expected. Below is my code.
To be clear, what I'm trying to achieve is to access properties of the userController and userModel in actually all of my templates/routes (some of which are computed). However, 'user' itself doesn't have a page, so that's why it's not added in the Router.map. It's just a really important class that handles everything user-related and handles access to the user-model. 
I hope somebody with a bit more ember experience knows what I'm doing wrong. Or maybe got some advice on how to do this the ember-way? Any help is greatly appreciated!
PS: I tried to be as complete as possible, if I'm forgetting smt let me know, I'll add it.

```
App.Router.map(function() {
this.resource('signup');
this.resource('login');
this.resource('profile');
this.resource('practice');
this.resource('overview');
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function () {
return this.store.find('user');
  }
});

App.LoginRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
controllerName: 'application',
model: function () {}
});

App.UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return this.store.find('user');
    }
});

//UserController
App.UserController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    //pagetitle property to test. Working.
    pageTitle: 'Usercontroller',
    //userArray property to test, but didn't work. 
    // Makes sense since the Arraycontroller return an array, so you'll have to use #each-helper
    userArray: function(){
    return this.get('content');
    },
    //particularUser computed property to test, but also didn't work. 
    // Neither did looping #each through the userArray property
    particularUser : Ember.computed.filterBy('content' , 'username', 'Sunchild')
});

//LoginController
App.LoginController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: ['user'],
    pageTitle: 'test-title loginController'
});

// Login template feeded into an outlet in the application template
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="login">
    <div class="content">
        <form class="input-group">
            <div class="input-row">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
            <div class="input-row">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" placeholder="ratchetframework@gmail.com">
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-outlined">Login</button>
        </form>
        <h3> test1:{{controllers.user.pageTitle}}</h3>
        <h3> test2:{{controllers.user.userArray}}</h3>
        {{#each user in controllers.user.particularUser}}
            <div class="card_wrapper">
                <p><h3>Username: {{{user.username}}}</h3><p>
                <p>email: {{user.email}}</p>
            </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a `user` route in your router, the `model` hook in your `UserRoute` will never run. That means that the model of your `UserController` will always be empty. So the way you've set things up won't work for your use case. **But**, you have the same model on your `ApplicationRoute`, so why not use that controller instead?

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    // Never use the `content` property, always use the `model` property, they are different
    userArray: Ember.computed.alias('model'),

    particularUser: function() {
        // Be sure to only grab the first item, not an array with the first item in it
        return this.get('userArray').filterBy('username', 'Sunchild').get('firstObject');
    }.property('userArray.@each.username')
});
```

This is nice because your application route runs before any other route, so this data will *always* be available. So in your `LoginController`:

```
App.LoginController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: ['application'],
    userArray: Ember.comptued.alias('controllers.application.userArray']
});
```

Hopefully that clears things up a bit.

Comment: Hi GJK, thanx for your response and explanation. I like the idea and I'm actually trying to implement it right now. I'll get back to you if all works out or not. TNX-a-lot.

Comment: I tried to call the computed property in the login-template with the #each helper, but it doesn't output anything:
'{{#each user in controllers.application.particularUser}}{{/each}}'
This still works as expected:
'{{#each user in controllers.application.userArray}}{{/each}}'
So are a controller's computed properties accessed differently in templates when it's controller is injected through the needs-property? In my understanding both should work the same way!?

Comment: Ok, I just found out it works when I remove the .get('firstObject') part from the computed property. Only then I can loop through the array with the #each-helper in the template and it gives me the single result. Any insights would be great! Apart from that very clear now, so thanx again!